# building dart on windows: build failed

Tags: dart

I'm trying to build the dart-vm on windows. I followed all steps described here https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/PreparingYourMachine and here https://code.google.com/p/dart/wiki/Building

When i try to execute the build.py script, i get the following error:

```
D:\_dev\workspace-vs\dart-repo\dart\tools>python build.py runtime
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\\devenv.com /build DebugX64|x64 /project runtime dart.sln

Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

The following files were specified on the command line:

    dart.sln

These files could not be found and will not be loaded.BUILD FAILED

D:\_dev\workspace-vs\dart-repo\dart\tools>
```

Is it even possible to build the vm on a windows system?

**edit:**

ok, so now, after i updated all visual studio solution files to my 2013 version, i can at least start the build chain. but i still get some errors. it seems i am unable to generate the 'global_intermediate' files, following solutions trying to build depend on them and fail. any ideas?

```
1>------ Build started: Project: generate_async_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: generate_corelib_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: generate_async_patch_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
4>------ Build started: Project: generate_collection_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
5>------ Build started: Project: generate_collection_patch_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
6>------ Build started: Project: generate_convert_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
7>------ Build started: Project: generate_convert_patch_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
8>------ Build started: Project: generate_typed_data_patch_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
2>  Generating ..\build\ReleaseIA32\obj/global_intermediate/corelib_gen.cc file.
2>  The system cannot find the path specified.
4>  Generating ..\build\ReleaseIA32\obj/global_intermediate/collection_gen.cc file.
4>  The system cannot find the path specified.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
3>  Generating ..\build\ReleaseIA32\obj/global_intermediate/async_patch_gen.cc file.
3>  The system cannot find the path specified.
9>------ Build started: Project: generate_corelib_patch_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
10>------ Build started: Project: generate_internal_cc_file, Configuration: ReleaseIA32 Win32 ------
1>  Generating ..\build\ReleaseIA32\obj/global_intermediate/async_gen.cc file.
10>  Generating ..\build\ReleaseIA32\obj/global_intermediate/internal_gen.cc file.
10>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Why dont you use a pre-compiled binary?

Comment: i would like to recreate the apache module that has been made here https://github.com/sam-mccall/mod_dart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. see https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20023 for more info how to build on vs2013.